# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined in materialize.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

Can anyone help me to overcome this error ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2Ngv.png)

This is script :

```
// usefull for select for example
  $.fn.scrollTo = function(elem) {
    $(this).scrollTop($(this).scrollTop() - $(this).offset().top + $(elem).offset().top);
    return this;
  };
```

and this is bug :

```
materialize.js:429 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
    at m.fn.init.$.fn.scrollTo (materialize.js:429)
    at activateOption (materialize.js:2731)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (materialize.js:2720)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (VM44 jquery-1.11.2.min.js:3)
    at HTMLInputElement.r.handle (VM44 jquery-1.11.2.min.js:3)
```

Comment: How are you calling the `scrollTo` function?

Comment: please reproduce your code on jsfiddle or plunker